# C++ 3D Model Animation libraries?

Tags: c++, animation, model, 3d

I have my own game engine using C++ and OpenGL, but I have models with individual pieces that can be moved, and Im not sure how to animate them without hardcoding it. Are there any libraries that would provide a solution via scripts or IK or some other animation technique without resorting to a game engine such as Ogre?

Comment: OGRE isn't a game engine, it's purely a graphics rendering engine.

Comment: aha, I can provide my own rendering engine, but whats rendered is somewhat static right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cal3d](http://home.gna.org/cal3d/) could be an option. Skinned character animation without needing to import a whole engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want physics, there are many open source physics engines, such as [ODE](http://www.ode.org/) and [box2D](http://www.box2d.org/).

If you want game-like behaviors, an embedding scripting language like [lua](http://www.lua.org/) is common for game engines.